How to create changing word animation in CSS?
I'm trying to achieve the effect of a changing word in the middle of a sentence, but I don't understand why the word after using the code runs away to the middle of the page instead of being where it was before adding the animation class.
I want this text to behave like this animation doesnt exist - no matter what position I use or what I delete, .word fragment is always in separated paragraph from rest of my text. I tried deleting position: absolute and top 50% left 50% from .word style, didnt help.
I want to achieve this look:
Strona, która zdobędzie za/dla (changing word) Ciebie klienta. - in one line, like normal text.
Code:
<head> </head>

<body>
<style>
.container {
            position: relative;
            font-family: inherit;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            font-size: inherit;
            filter: contrast(15);
        }

.word {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            animation: switch 8s infinite ease-in-out;
            min-width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
        }
 
        .word:nth-child(1) {
            animation-delay: -7s;
        }
 
        .word:nth-child(2) {
            animation-delay: -6s;
        }
 
        .word:nth-child(3) {
            animation-delay: -5s;
        }
 
        @keyframes switch {
 
            0%,
            5%,
            100% {
                filter: blur(0px);
                opacity: 1;
            }
 
            50%,
            80% {
                filter: blur(180px);
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
</style>

<div class="container">

Stworzymy stronę, która zdobędzie <div class="word">dla</div> <div class="word">za</div> Ciebie klienta.

</div>

I tried changing position and almost all of the settings in Wordpress & Elementor. Watched a couple of guides, but none of them helped.

You are only animating the blur radius and the opacity here, so that means all these words you want to "switch" between, need to be in the same position to begin with. You could still center them using the technique currently used - and then position the left and right part of the sentence accordingly. But that will probably not work very good, in terms of responsiveness. [...]

[...]Wrapping all the words into an additional (inline) container, and then positioning every one except the longest, absolute in that container (so that the longest word spans up the necessary width for the container), might work as an alternative.
